# different action to index page. how to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code:

```
<% @cars.each do |car| %>
  <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">
    <%= link_to image_tag( car.profile_avatar.asset.url(:thumb) ), car %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

..which will display the number of cars that are defined in the `index` action:

```
def index
  @search = Car.search(params[:search])
  @cars   = @search.all.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 5
```

..so I'll have 5 images in the slider. I can't change it because I use it for the main `<div>`.

The question is, how do I make another statement in the controller and how do I make a reference to it in the view so that I can have more car pictures in the slider?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.. I just add a new instance in controller like

```
@cars_footer = @search.all.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 3
```

then I call it in the view with

```
<% @cars_footer.each do |car| %>
  <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">
    <%= link_to image_tag( car.profile_avatar.asset.url(:thumb) ), car %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

SO easy... well.. I am new in rails.